# Linking an individual through an object property to a class?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl

I have an ontology that contains the following classes:

"Property", "PropertyType". The "PropertyType" class has two sub classes "ReadableProperty" and "WritetableProperty".

The ontology also contains an object property "hasPropertyType" with the domain "Property" and range "PropertyType".

Is it semantically correct to create the following triples (link an individual of a class to a another class through an object property):

```
PREFIX exmp:<http://example.org/myontology.owl#>

INSERT DATA{
    exmp:someindividual rdf:type exmp:Property, owl:NamedIndividual.
    exmp:someindividual exmp:hasPropertyType exmp:WritetableProperty.
}
```

?

Or should I link the individual of the "Property" class to an individual of the "WritetableProperty" class, and not to the class it self?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#Property:

> OWL distinguishes between two main categories of properties that an
>   ontology builder may want to define:
>
> ```
> Object properties link individuals to individuals.
> Datatype properties link individuals to data values.
> ```

So to answer your question: the second option is the correct one.

Don't get confused with defining the `Domain` and `Range` for object properties on the terminological level, with the actual assertion of a property.